# How to manually compare two different powers of any two different natural numbers (is there a universal algorithm)?

Tags: exponentiation

The ability of manually comparing any powers of any natural numbers is one of my greatest dreams. "Manually" means without a calculator, or a computer, or any other device besides my own head and possibly also a pencil and paper.

For example, we need to compare 17⁹⁷ and 63⁶⁴.

In a video published on Youtube I learnt an interesting algorithm.

17 > 16. Thus, 17⁹⁷ > 16⁹⁷ = (2⁴)⁹⁷ = 2³⁸⁸.

63 < 64. Thus, 63⁶⁴ < 64⁶⁴ = (2⁶)⁶⁴ = 2³⁸⁴.

So, finally, 17⁹⁷ > 63⁶⁴.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpZZ6DSVI3o

This is very interesting and instructive, but I feel that it may not work in some cases. E.g. we must compare 12⁶⁷ and 8⁷⁷. I fear that the above mentioned algorithm will fail.

12 > 8. Thus, 12⁶⁷ > 8⁶⁷ = (2³)⁶⁷ = 2²⁰¹. Or, on the other hand, 12 < 16. Thus, 12⁶⁷ < 16⁶⁷ = (2⁴)⁶⁷ = 2²⁶⁸.
And 8⁷⁷ = (2³)⁷⁷ = 2²³¹.

So we now know that 12⁶⁷ lies between 2²⁰¹ and 2²⁶⁸, but it is unclear if it is greater or less than 2²³¹ = 8⁷⁷.

And as of taking the logarithms... Yes, it solves the problem, of course. I know that any logarithm with a base greater than 1 is a strictly increasing function. So instead of direct comparison of powers we can take either decimal or natural logarithms of both our numbers (the exponent will become a factor) and then compare the resulting logarithms with each other. But... my question is about how to **manually** compare the powers. And unfortunately I do not know how to take an arbitrary logarithm without usage of a calculator.

So is there a universal algorithm which works in every single case? (Or, if it isn't, is there a way to somehow prove that it doesn't exist?)

Comment: Yes, there is a universal algorithm. For instance, to determine the larger of $12^{67}$ and $8^{77}$, compute $12\times 12\times\ldots\times 12$ ($67$ factors of $12$) and $8\times 8\times\ldots\times 8$ ($77$ factors of $8$) and compare the results. :-)

Comment: It would be hard to show $2^{15}>181^2$ without either multiplying everything out or using logarithms, as $2^{15}=32768$, $181^2=32761$. Powers can be pretty close together.